# update record using ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Can anyone help me regarding updating data in the gridview by using AJAX?

Once values are entered into textboxes and saved into Database, then gridview has to update the new changes. And not by using the ajax updatepanel

Comment: you have an asp page with a form, where the user inputs data and a gridview should update, but you do not want to use updatepanel? where does this limitation come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why exactly are you avoiding an updatepanel? It is the simplest option.

You can use Ajax functions for several things like keyboard support or bringing a popup for data editing, but for refresh, I have found that updatepanel works the best.